# integrate multiple service response in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

When I get request form path for example /bar is it possible in spring cloud gateway  to call multiple microservices and integrate their result (for example JSON) and send  as response of /bar ?
How can i do it?
thanks

Comment: There is an open issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProxyExchange to help you composition multiple responses.

An example given by Spring Cloud:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaySampleApplication {

    @Value("${remote.home}")
    private URI home;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> proxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
        return proxy.uri(home.toString() + "/image/png").get();
    }

}
```

In this case it is only used to return the ResponseEntity, but you can use it however you like. In your case you can combine multiple ResponseEntities.